# Add attribute to existing datomic schema

Tags: clojure, schema, datomic

I'm attempting to add an attribute to an existing datomic schema, with the new attribute being

```
  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :user-deets/enriched
  :db/valueType :db.type/boolean
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

and when I try to submit it as a transaction (as described  at http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html) with the following

```
(datomic/query '[{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
      :db/ident :user-deets/enriched
      :db/valueType :db.type/boolean
      :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
      :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}] (database/get-db))
```

I get an error that I don't have a :find clause in my query.

How should I be submitting this transaction in order to add the attribute to my datomic databases schema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you're using the wrong function.

You want to use `transact` [See doc](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/transact).

```
(datomic/transact connection [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :user-deets/enriched
  :db/valueType :db.type/boolean
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}])
```

Answer (score -1):

For an even easier time creating attributes and using other Datomic features, you may wish to try [the Tupelo Datomic library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/tupelo/datomic.adoc). It will allow you to create attributes like this:

```
(:require [tupelo.datomic :as td])

  ; Create some new attributes. Required args are the attribute name (an optionally namespaced
  ; keyword) and the attribute type (full listing at http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html). We wrap
  ; the new attribute definitions in a transaction and immediately commit them into the DB.
  (td/transact *conn* ;   required              required              zero-or-more
                      ;  <attr name>         <attr value type>       <optional specs ...>
    (td/new-attribute   :person/name         :db.type/string         :db.unique/value)      ; each name      is unique
    (td/new-attribute   :person/secret-id    :db.type/long           :db.unique/value)      ; each secret-id is unique
    (td/new-attribute   :weapon/type         :db.type/ref            :db.cardinality/many)  ; one may have many weapons
    (td/new-attribute   :location            :db.type/string)     ; all default values
    (td/new-attribute   :favorite-weapon     :db.type/keyword ))  ; all default values
```

In your case, this would simplify to

```
(td/transact (database/get-db)
  (td/new-attribute :user-deets/enriched :db.type/boolean))
```